# How to handle missing data in a logistic regression?

Tags: logistic-regression, missing-data

I am building a model to solve a binary classification task. So far, the input is low dimensional (10 dimensions at most). I need to face the occurrences of missing input. It is my first time at trying to handle that. I am thinking of doing some feature engineering where I add a binary variable for each dimension taking values `1` if missing and `0` if not.
This is a data based solution. Are there canonical ways or known better of handling this in the literature? What are the limitations or weaknesses of my train of thoughts?

Comment: What kind of variable is it? How many datapoints have missing values?

Comment: All my base inputs are continuous inputs constrained to a `[0,1]` range. I do not know in advance of the fraction of missing values. The assumptions that it is low (<1%) is very plausible.

Comment: Under the assumption that the chance of this variable having missing values is very slim (as you commented), don't worry about it too much. You can start by taking the mean of the variable values and fill in the missing values. 

Please note that adding categorical variables indicating missing/not missing still won't help you deal with the missing data itself...

Comment: I thought of using an imputer but it is expected that there is some discriminative information in a missing input. I prefer not to drop this information.

Comment: Are the data missing at random? You will need different strategies depending on the answer.

Comment: Yes and not, there is both scenarios: random miss but also intentional miss from some users. I am not sure how they compare in terms of frequency of occurence. Ideally the model is accounting for both.